# Trying to push one local repository to the other

Tags: git, repository, push

Hi stackOverFlow experts!

There are 2 repositories in their own subfolders under drive C on my machine (A and B) as follows:

- repository A which comes from a git clone of some remote repo (found in c:\devA)
- repository B which comes from a clone of svn with git svn clone (found in c:\clone\devB)

I want to push devB to devA and tried to do the following:

```
git remote add master /c/devA
git push master --all
```

I received the following error:

```
fatal: 'c:/devA' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can anyone help me with this?  Thank you!!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work the way you're using it, so I see two options:

- c:/devA is not a git repository (please check for .git folder)
- there's something wrong with Windows path

Comment: You're right- something happened to my .git folder...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use repos together, they must be cloned from the same repository, creating two repositories and then linking them doesn't work.